# Dynamically created summernote textarea - how to trigger function on change

Tags: jquery, html, summernote

I am dynamically creating a summernote text area and populating it with the initial data. When this data is changed I want to call a funtion to update the database. For an 'input' field 'onchange' works (is triggered when you make a change and then leave the field) so I tried it here as per below. This did not work (was not triggered on leaving the field) and there is no console log message.

```js
var  json = json + "<textarea class='summernote col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' id='ymSpecificLine' name='ymSpecificLine' rows='1'"
              + "' onchange='taskDetailUpdateFunction(\"" + awardDetail.getAdDescription().replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\", \"" + encoded_task_detail_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")'>";
    json = json + awardDetail.getAdDescription();
    json = json + "</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Summernote have methods that can be called for this:
https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#callbacks

You'd call the onChange method as defined here:
https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onchange

Comment: I have been working away at this with the wysiwyg sometimes showing and then not showing (just a text box) when I leave the page and then re-display it. Finally, through trial and error, I found that the "" $('.summernote').summernote({});" and "$('.summernote').on('summernote.blur', function() {
   alert('Editable area loses focus');
  });" must go after the "$(responseJson1a).appendTo($("#button-container"));". So there is one tip for anyone who comes after me.

Comment: The next issue is that the blur function is triggered whether or not a change is made. Is there a way to only notify when leaving the editor when a change is made? This would need to capture if someone made a change and then deleted the change before leaving, the net effect is no change.

Comment: Two more issues: The blur is triggered when the toolbar is used. The blur goes into an endless loop if you click from one editor into another. I am dynamically creating a number of editors in this piece of work.

Comment: OK, don't use "alert" to resolve the loop. However, still the problem that using the toolbar triggers the blur.

Answer (score 1):

a simple one liner might help.

```
$('.summernote').trigger('summernote.change');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject it in your DOM with `innerHTML`:

```js
var json = "<textarea class='summernote col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' id='ymSpecificLine' name='ymSpecificLine' rows='1' onchange='onChange()'></textarea>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = json;

function onChange(){
  console.log("Value changed to: "+document.getElementById("ymSpecificLine").value);
}
```

```html
<p>Change my value then press TAB:</p>
<div id="demo"></div>
```